Does an MCZ gate flip the phase of the target qubit if it is in the 0 state?
I am trying to flip the phase of the solution state in an oracle for Grover's algorithm. I am wondering if an MCZ gate will flip the target qubit of |0> if the control qubits are in their correct states. Thanks

No. In order to get the phase flipped if the target qubit is 0, you need to add X gates before and after applying the MCZ gate:

